# Phonegap alert popup from server

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cordova

So at the moment there are 2 things:

- Phonegap side which has "the game" on it as app with JavaScript/html/CSS running.
- Server which handles database and has an admin side (accessible through web-browser, PHP/JavaScript/html/CSS).

Currently what i am struggling with is that from the server side you would have a "Start game" button once the admin pressed this button the Phonegap side would need an alert or some sort of popup in the app itself that shows the game has begun for all players.

As for now  i want an error message like an Alert which for example will be called once on the Phonegap side as soon as the administrator will press the "start game" button on his side. Maybe a possibility like having a function on Phonegap side that will be called once when the button is pressed? So i should be able to make this alert popup on the app through Phonegap with the start game button that is located on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have an interval, in which the client asks the server, whether the game started or not. This is easily possible with an Ajax call from within Phonegap. The clients do not have a fixed IP-Adress, which the Server could use to send them data, and peer-to-peer is not yet supportet in JavaScript HTML at all.

The Ajax call is really small, so don't worry about traffic.

You might be able to use Java within Phonegap, which handles the peer-to-peer connection, but that is probably not too easy.